# Why is the f:param returning null?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jboss-4.2.x

jsf 1.2, jboss 4.2.3 and richfaces 3.3.3

I'm trying to send the index of a  as a , but it keeps returning null:

```
<ui:repeat id="al11" var="albumslistvalue1" value="#{AlbumDetailBean.getAlbumImagesList()}" varStatus="listimages">
  <h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="proxima" id="next" action="#{AlbumDetailBean.escreveparam()}">
      <f:param name="fotoid" value="#{listimages}" />
    </h:commandLink>
  </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

the escreveparam() method only writes the param:

```
public void escreveparam(){
    String fotoid = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getParameter("fotoid");
    System.out.println("Teste:" + fotoid);
}
```

Why is it always null?

Comment: I tried to use a static value on f:param and it worked:
<f:param name="fotoid" value="2"/>

i don't get it, i'm using the #{listimages} on another components id so they are dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using JSF 1.x which thus implies that you're using Facelets 1.x (as in `jsf-facelets.jar` file). The `<ui:repeat>` tag has in [Facelets 1.x](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template-repeat) **no** `varStatus` attribute. It was been introduced in [Facelets 2.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html).

You need to look for alternate means. E.g. `<c:forEach>`

```html
<c:forEach value="#{bean.albums}" var="album" varStatus="loop">
  <h:form>
    <h:commandLink id="next" value="proxima" action="#{bean.next}">
      <f:param name="id" value="#{loop.index}" />
    </h:commandLink>
  </h:form>
</c:forEach>
```

*(please note that your initial usage of `varStatus` object was completely wrong, it does not give you the raw index back, but a [complete object](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) holding all iteration status details, with among others a `getIndex()` method, you should actually have used `#{listimages.index}` or something instead --provided that you were using Facelets 2.x)*

or just the ID of the iterated `Album` object itself

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.albums}" var="album">
  <h:form>
    <h:commandLink id="next" value="proxima" action="#{bean.next}">
      <f:param name="id" value="#{album.id}" />
    </h:commandLink>
  </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

either way, just use `<managed-property>` in `faces-config.xml` with a value of `#{param.id}` or the `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` to retrieve it:

```
public void next() {
    String id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
    // ...
}
```

By the way, since your environment seems to support JBoss EL (as indicated by using full method names with parentheses in EL), you could also just pass the whole `Album` as the action method argument

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.albums}" var="album">
  <h:form>
    <h:commandLink id="next" value="proxima" action="#{bean.next(album)}" />
  </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

with

```
public void next(Album album) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to use the id of the iterated Album object, but what i still don't understand is why eclipse and jboss recognize varStatus even using jsf 1.x and facelets 1.x
also, is it possible to use facelets 2.x with jsf 1.2 ?

Comment: You're welcome. No, Facelets 2 is bundled with JSF 2 and cannot be used independently with JSF 1.x.